# Angular - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵpipe')

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I've upgraded my Angular application from V15 -> V16. Since this upgrade a couple of my tests are showing the error:

```
 ExampleComponent › should create component   
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵpipe')

      35 |
      36 |   beforeEach(async () => {
    > 37 |     await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
```

Wondering if anyone has had the issue previously, and what they found it be causing it

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the node_modules and Angular cache?

Comment: @JSONDerulo Cleaning node_modules does nothing. I have found that by removing the injected dependency the test start working again.. 

I'll update the question if I find anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things I did to fix this issue:

- Within my @NgModule added the services as providers

```
@NgModule({
imports: [],
providers: [ExampleService]
)};
```

- Added service within test ExampleComponent.spec

```
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [ExampleComponent],
          imports: [
            NoopAnimationsModule,
            CommonModule
          ],
          providers: [ExampleService]
        }).compileComponents();
      });
```

- ***Main Fix*** - Within the component import the services like:

`import { ExampleService } from '../../services/Example.service';`

and not like:

`import { ExampleService } from '../../services';`